# Get number of words in an array starting with certain characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to solve a problem on a testing website and I'm getting confused on trying to find a way to match the letters of a passed in array wordlist.

In the below example it should be returning `2`, as `ye` should be matched twice - in `yesterday` and `yellow`.

Without using a RegEx what would be the best way be to go about getting a passed in wordlist to return a number amount based on the 2nd argument input?

This is the code I have so far, that isn't working:

```js
let wordList = ['yesterday', 'develop', 'environment', 'yellow', 'yikes', 'envious']

const countingLetters = (words, inputStart) => {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (inputStart == words[i]) {
      total += 1;
    }
  }
  return total;
};


console.log(countingLetters(wordList, 'ye'));
```

Comment: Are the words supposed to start with the `inputStart` string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require without a regex, you can use the `filter()` function, to search the array by a given condition, and the `indexOf()` method to ensure that the match is at the start of the string:

```js
let wordList = ['yesterday', 'develop', 'environment', 'yellow', 'yikes', 'envious']

const countingLetters = (words, inputStart) => 
  words.filter(word => word.indexOf(inputStart) === 0).length;

console.log(countingLetters(wordList, 'ye'));
```

Comment: I'm just about to start learning about RegEx. Following on from what you've said, Rory, can you please show me how it would be done in RegEx. You've been a great help so far!

Comment: Sure, here's the above modified to use Regex. Note the use of the `^` character as it restricts matches to there start of the word only: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rjwvegqx/

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for taking the time out of your day to help me. Have a good rest of your Sunday.